# how to append an item to a list in an existing handelbar template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to append a list in an existing handlebar template. The code below allows me to add a comment but in order for the new comment to appear in the list with the existing comments I need to refresh. What I am wondering is how to append the new comment to the existing comment list in the template. I've included the entire template, but the place where I am trying to add the new comment is the ul with id bodyOfComments. thanks for the help.

```
 var comment_post = function() {

    // console.log($(this).attr("data-id"))
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/comments',     
        type: 'POST',
        data: {comment: {
            body: $('#content').find('input[name="createComment"]').val(),
            user_id: 1,
            image_set_id: $(this).attr("data-id")}
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#imageSetTemplate').html());
          $('#bodyOfComments').append(template({
            comment: response
        }));

    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#content').on('click', '#submitComment', comment_post)
});
```

code below is the handlebars template in html file

```
<script id="imageSetTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <h1>{{image_set.voting_criteria}}</h1>


    <div class="continer">
      <div class="row">
        {{#each image_set.images}}
        <div class = "col-xs-4"><img src={{this.image_url}}></div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul id="bodyOfComments">
      {{#each image_set.comments}}
        <li> {{this.body}} </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <button type="submit" id="submitComment" data-id={{image_set.id}}>Create Comment</button>
    <input name="createComment" id="commentBody">




</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the comments template out to be a separate template.

```
<script id="commentsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#comments}}
      <li> {{.}} </li>
    {{/comments}}
</script>
```

Then you can append as following.

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($('#commentsTemplate').html());
  $('#bodyOfComments').append(template({
    comments: response
  }));
```